# How to fix error code for " information gain, entropy" used to create data.txt file

Tags: python

I have this code :

```
door, window, occupancy_data = [],[],[]
file = open("data.txt",'r')
Title = file.readline()
for line in file:
  line_token = line.split(";")
  door.append(float(line_token[0])),
  window.append(float(line_token[1])),
  occupancy_data.append(float(line_token[2])) # store the values of each column in information_gain.txt in 3 seperate lists
file.close()
print(occupancy_data)
def information_gain(feature_data, occupancy_data):
    occupancy_data0,occupancy_data1,feature_data0,feature_data1 = [],[],[]
    for i in range(len(occupancy_data)):
      if feature_data[i] == 0:
        feature_data().append(feature_data[i])
        occupancy_data().append(occupancy_data[i])
    else: 
      feature_data1.append(feature_data[i])
      occupancy_data1.append(occupancy_data[i])
    entropy0, entropy1 = entropy(occupancy_data0), entropy(occupancy_data1)
    return entropy(occupancy_data) - (len(feature_data0)/len(occupancy_data)) * entropy0 - (len(feature_data1)/len(occupancy_data)) * entropy1
```

I keep getting this answer:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/User/Dropbox/manage/example2.py", line 2, in
>
> file = open("data.txt",'r')
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.txt'

Comment: well, looks like that file *data.txt* doesn't exist or isn't in the folder you are opening :)

Comment: I tried creating a file in my working directory but still to no avail, this is my first time with machine learning and I really would like to know how to go about it before moving to the next exercise